# How to insert or update current timestamp as NumberLong in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, shell, timestamp, robo3t

I have given a try to perform the following query:

```
.update({}, 
        {
          "type" : "negative",
          "createdAt" : new Date() // here instead get NumberLong for current timestamp
        }
, {upsert: true})
```

But this results in :

```
"createdAt" : ISODate("2020-01-15T16:23:15.265Z")
```

instead what I am looking for is:

```
"createdAt" : NumberLong(1563199234901)
```

I am using Robo3T shell to execute these queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now):

```
"createdAt" : new NumberLong(Date.now())
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped, but should be `"createdAt": new NumberLong(Date.now())` to be precise.

Comment: It should indeed